# Trying to use a 3rd criteria for autofilter, getting compile error?

Tags: vba, excel

Is the syntax limit really just two? So I have to either use an array or just repeat the block of code? The error is at `Criteria3:=` in my `.AutoFilter Field` - `Compile error: Named argument not found`. I'm just surprised that it's limited to two. What is the reason behind this?

```
Sub CleanData()
    'B b b b boilerplate!

    Dim sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, myrange As Range

        'Set references up-front
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")

        'Identify the last row and use that info to set up the Range
        With sht
            lastrow = .Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set myrange = .Range("A2:AS" & lastrow)
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            With myrange

                'Apply the Autofilter method to the first column of
                .AutoFilter Field:=26, _
                            Criteria1:="Operator Error", _
                            Operator:=xlOr, _
                            Criteria2:="Duplicate", _
                            Operator:=xlOr, _
                            Criteria3:="Training/Test"
                            'ERROR HERE 

                'Delete the visible rows while keeping the header
                On Error Resume Next
                .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'Turn off the AutoFilter
        With sht
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            If .FilterMode = True Then
                .ShowAllData
            End If
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's correct, the limit for filter criteria is 2. I ran into this frustrating limit once and did not find any easy alternatives. You will need to be creative with what you are trying to achieve to workaround this limitation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Criteria3`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) is not a valid parameter., but to get around this, you can use an array:

(Filtering on multiple states)

```
Criteria1:=Array("IL", "IN", "MI", "OH", "WV"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Aha - I knew there had to be a better way. Thanks